# Running Nodebb in Kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes

I'm very new to Kubernetes cluster management. I have completed kubernetes cluster setup with 2 nodes up and running. So for getting started I decided to run NodeBB app on Cluster. So instead of building my own image got official NodeBB docker container at [Docker HUb](https://hub.docker.com/r/nodebb/docker/)

So to startup NodeBB from that container i fired command at Kubernetes master.

```html
kubectl run nodebbtest --image=nodebb/docker:ubuntu  --port=4567 --replicas=2
```

After waiting for some time it started containers with two replicas. But the problem is it is keep restarting my containers.

Any know why this is happening?

Comment: Did you try to check the logs for these pods? 
kubectl logs <pod-name>

Comment: I'd assume it's the pods themselves that are falling over, then kubernetes is trying to restart them.  I agree with @George, check the logs.

Comment: `kubectl get pods` to find name of actual pod, then `kubectl logs <podname>` to see the logs.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation on https://hub.docker.com/r/nodebb/docker/, it sounds like you need to provide configuration to Nodebb, which you are not doing.

If you want to try running this interactively first, as in the example, kubectl run supports that: kubectl run -i --tty ...

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/user-guide/kubectl/kubectl_run.md

Try one replica first.